# Why objects props passed to child components are 'undefinded' but primitives work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a hard time understanding why a child component is not properly receiving an object passed from the parent's props.

parent:

```js
import React from 'react';

import StockSummary from '../stock_show/stock_header';

const OwnedListItem = ({ ownedStock }) => (
  <div className="">
    <h4>Ticker: {ownedStock.ticker}</h4> // works

    <StockSummary quote={ownedStock.quote} /> // throws 'undefined' error
  </div>
);

export default OwnedListItem;
```

child:

```js
import React from 'react';

const StockSummary = ({ quote }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Stock Summary</h3>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Avg Total Volume</td>
          <td>{quote.avgTotalVolume}</td>
        </tr>
        
 ...
```

The Error [image]

This is the object that is being passed to the Parent, seen above.

[image]

As you can see, the data is there, I just do not have an understanding of why objects can't be passed to children as props.

Thanks.

EDIT Add quote obj:

[image]

EDIT Add rendered Markup:

```html
<div>
  <h3>Stock Summary</h3>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Avg Total Volume</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Latest Volume</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>P/E Ratio</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Market Cap</td>
        <td><!-- react-text: 105 -->NaN<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 106 -->B<!-- /react-text --></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>52 Week High</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>52 Week Low</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>YTD Change</td>
        <td><!-- react-text: 116 -->NaN<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 117 -->%<!-- /react-text --></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

EDIT Changing the parent to map over the 'ownedStock' object allowed me to pass the correct data to the child. Does this make sense to you guys?

```js
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import StockSummary from '../stock_show/stock_summary';

const OwnedListItem = ({ ownedStock }) => (
  <div className="">
    {Object.keys(ownedStock).map(key => {
      if (key === 'quote') {
        return <StockSummary quote={ownedStock[key]} />
      }
    })}
  </div>
);

export default OwnedListItem;
```

EDIT: `console.log(quote)` in child component
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the `quote` object please?

Comment: i guess you need to use `this.props.quote....`

Comment: The 'quote' obj is added. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change this  `<StockSummary quote={ownedStock.quote} />` to  `<StockSummary quote={ownedStock} />`

Comment: Thanks. This cleared the error, but the data from 'quote' is not being passed to the child. It is being rendered 'empty', I guess you could say.

Comment: Could you inspect and paste the child component's rendered markup here ?

Comment: I copied the rendered HTML within DevTools. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: can you change your child component to const StockSummary = ({ quote }) => { console.log(quote) return( //your makrup )} and see what is being logged in console.

Comment: As you can see, the object is not being destructured.

Answer (score 0):

Objects ***can*** be passed to children as props. It sounds like the `ownedStock` prop might be an object of objects, rather than a simple object. This would explain why the `.map()` over the object keys works. I'm guessing `ownedStock` is something like:

```
var ownedStock = {
  ABAX: {
    ticker: "GOOG",
    quote: {
      avgTotalVolume: 20
    }
  }
};
```

If you don't want to `.map()` over the `ownedStock` because you're absolutely positive there's only one item in the `ownedStock` object, and you know it's key, you can do this:

```js
var ownedStock = {
  ABAX: {
    ticker: "GOOG",
    quote: {
      avgTotalVolume: 20
    }
  }
};

const OwnedListItem = ({ ownedStock }) => (
  <div className="">
    <h4>Ticker: {ownedStock.ticker}</h4> // works

    <StockSummary quote={ownedStock.quote} />
  </div>
);

const StockSummary = ({ quote }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Stock Summary</h3>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Avg Total Volume</td>
          <td>{quote.avgTotalVolume}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  )
  
  
ReactDOM.render(<OwnedListItem ownedStock={ownedStock.ABAX}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If you don't know the key, you'll need map over the object keys like you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks Brett. I added some additional info. Would you mind taking another look? Thanks!